# Finite field extension $[F:f]=2$ with $\operatorname{Char}(f)=2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F/f$ be a field extension with $[F:f]=2$ and $\operatorname{Char}(f)\ne2$.

(a) Show that there is an $a\in F$ such that $F = f(a)$ and $a^2\in f$.

(b) Show that (a) doesn't hold when $\operatorname{Char}(f)= 2$

---

I showed (a), but I don't see how $\operatorname{Char}(f)\ne2$ is necessary there, so I also don't see how this fails when $\operatorname{Char}(f)= 2$.
I showed (a) by inferring that there must be an $a \in F$ and $a \notin f$ and that $\{1,a\}$ is a basis for $F$. 
I don't have Galois Theory at my disposal yet, so I have to do this in an elementary fashion.

Comment: How does the fact that $\{1,a\}$ is a basis for $F$ imply that $a^2\in f$?

Comment: Statement (b) should be interpreted to mean that (a) *sometimes* fails; it doesn't always fail when $f$ has characteristic 2.  The simplest example where it fails is to let $f$ be the 2-element field and let $F$ be the 4-element field.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Right; I looked carefully for any finiteness assumption in the question and found none.  Fearing that the OP might be trying to prove "always", I thought I'd better head off that notion.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument for (a) must be fault if you din't use the assumption baout the characteristic.

(a) Pick $b\in F\setminus f$. Then $1,b,b^2$ are $f$-linearly dependent.
Then there are $a_0,a_1,a_2\in f$ (not all $0$) with $a_0+a_1b+a_2b^2=0$.
If $a_2=0$ we conclude that $1,b$ are linearly dependent, which is absurd. Hence $a_2\ne 0$. Wlog. $a_2=1$. If $2$ is invertible, then with $a:=b+2^{-1}a_1$ we have 
$$ a^2=(b+2^{-1}a_1)^2=b^2+a_1b+2^{-2}a_1^2=2^{-2}a_1^2-a_0\in f$$
whereas $a\in f$ would imply $b\in f$.

(b) In characteristic $2$ let $f=\Bbb F_2$ and $F=\Bbb F_4$. $a^2=1$ implies $a=1$ and $a^2=0$ implies $a=0$.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Yes, my argument for (a) was very wrong ;-)